# Is there a way to detect browser autofill or psuedo classes in angular or JS

Tags: javascript, angular

Is there a way to detect browser autofill in input? I knew the CSS way using `:-webkit-autofill`. Itried using `ViewChild Element` reference to detect the `Psuedo class`. But, it returns false. Any idea how to detect the browser autofill using angular.
If not, how to detect the psuedo class using angular.
**Note: this.el.nativeElement.classList.contains(':-webkit-autofill');** didn't work for Psuedo classes

Comment: Can you add your code?